# models within a box are jittery. How to prevent the vibration?

Tags: gazebo-model, sdformat, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to make a box that contains multiple balls. However as soon as I add a second layer of balls, the balls in the first layer begin to vibrate. Is there any specific values that i need to add to prevent this from happening.

edit: It seems that the balls do not have enough space in the lower layer and begin vibrating instead of rearranging themselves.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23866/models-within-a-box-are-jittery.-how-to-prevent-the-vibration?/) by [adheeshenoy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16031/adheeshenoy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-09-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dkoung](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16763/dkoung/) on 2019-10-01**:
probably you should set a parameter called *max_depth*, ex:

```
<collision name="collision0">
      <surface>
        <contact>
          <ode>
            <min_depth>0.01</min_depth>
          </ode>
        </contact>
     </surface>
</collision>
```

You can check this [link](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/test/worlds/contact_stability.world) for a comparison between different values of *max_depth*

**Comment by [adheeshenoy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16031/adheeshenoy/) on 2019-10-01**:
@dkoung Thanks for the response. I tried the following and it did not solve the problem. The issue I observed is that there is not enough space for all the balls in the lower layer and so they collide with each other instead of rearranging themselves.

**Comment by [dkoung](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16763/dkoung/) on 2019-10-02**:
Edit to my previous response: it's *min_depth* not *max_depth*, sorry.

Also try *max_vel*=0.0, it is maximum interpenetration error correction velocity. By setting it to 0, interpenetrating objects will not be pushed apart.

```
<collision name="collision0">
  <surface>
    <contact>
      <ode>
        <min_depth>0.01</min_depth>
        <max_vel>0.0</max_vel>
      </ode>
    </contact>
  </surface>
</collision>
```

**Comment by [adheeshenoy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16031/adheeshenoy/) on 2019-10-02**:
@dkoung Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [dkoung](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16763/dkoung/) on 2019-10-03**:
@adheeshenoy You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So the answer is:
Making max_vel=0.0 and adding min_depth to a really small value like 0.01.
For example:

```
<collision name="collision0">
<surface>
    <contact>
      <ode>
        <min_depth>0.01</min_depth>
        <max_vel>0.0</max_vel>
      </ode>
    </contact>
  </surface>
</collision>
```

Thank you to dkoung for the answer.

---

Originally posted by [adheeshenoy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16031/adheeshenoy/) with karma: 23 on 2019-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0